# Input array is longer

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, gridview, datatable

I try to display data in grid view through web method and jquery function so i try this. I try to display gridview when user select value from drop-down and select dates from calendar

```
$(function () {
              $('[ID*=search_data]').on('click', function () {
                  var fromdate = $('[ID*=fromdate]').val();
                  var todate = $('[ID*=todate]').val();
                  var regiondrop = $('[ID*=regiondrop] option:selected')[0].value;
                  var GridView1 = $('[ID*=GridView1]');
                  var obj = {};
                  obj.fromdate = fromdate;
                  obj.todate = todate;
                  obj.regiondrop = regiondrop;
                 Getdataa(obj);
                 });
         });
         function Getdataa(obj) {
             //alert('1');
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "WebForm1.aspx/search_data",
                 data: "{'fromdate':'" + obj.fromdate + "','todate':'" + obj.todate + "','regiondrop':'" + obj.regiondrop + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: true,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                     $("#GridView1").empty();
                     if (result.d.length > 0) {
                         $("#GridView1").append(
       "<tr><th>ID</th><th>OName</th><th>Reg No</th><th>Speed</th></tr>");

                         for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                             $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" +
              result.d[i].ID+ "</td> <td>" +
              result.d[i].OName + "</td> <td>" +
               result.d[i].Reg No+ "</td> <td>" +
              result.d[i].Speed+ "</td></tr>");
                         }
                     }
                     else {
                         $("#GridView1").hide();
                         $("#Label1").text("No Data");
                     }
                 },
                 error: function (error) {
                     alert("error");

                 }
             });
         }
```

WebMethod

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static DataTable search_data(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string regiondrop)
    {
        try
        {
            T1 ts = new T1();
            var dq = (from vv in ts.tblVe
                      join rv in ts.tblRe on vv.ID equals rv.ID
                      join re in ts.tblReg on rv.RID equals re.RID
                      where
                      re.Region == regiondrop
                      && re.StartDate <= fromdate
                      && re.EndDate >= todate
                      orderby
                      vv.ID,
                      rv.OwnerName
                      select new
                      { 
                          ID=rv.ID,
                          OName = rv.OName ,
                          RegNo = rv.RegNo,
                          Speed = rv.Speed ,
                      }).ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Rows.Add(dq);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();

        }
    }
```

in var dq.. dq show this data

```
[0] = { ID = 1, OName = "Khan", RegNo = "AJ-24",Speed = "124" } [1] = { ID = 2, OName = "Shah", RegNo = "AL-91",Speed = "95" }
```

**UPDATE**

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("OName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("RegNo", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Speed", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(dq);
            return dt;
```

and exception occur

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]> in ID Column.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add the columns in you datatable

```
dt.Columns.Add();
```

for more information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but i add columns in my jquery .. i bind gridview in jquery

Comment: the exception is thrown in the asp.net web method, there you need to add the columns  in the datatable  before inserting the data into it., the columns defined in jquery will not add any column information in the datatable you have defined in webmethod

Comment: check my update code i add columns but still same error occur @Deep

Comment: you are adding columns info after pushing the data in table. this is why same error is there

Comment: now i add return dt at the end but same error occur

Comment: i meant before adding row into the datatable 
 First Step
         dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
         dt.Columns.Add("OName",typeof(string));
         dt.Columns.Add("RegNo",typeof(string));
         dt.Columns.Add("Speed",typeof(string));   Second Step dt.Rows.Add(dq);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117472/discussion-between-deep-and-super-user).

Comment: i am done with this but still error check update @Deep